# Присоединение Button к ячейке Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть сетка Grid. Мне необходимо в конкретную ячейку (Grid.Row, Grid.Column) присоединить элемент Button, но сделать это нужно из кода, без использования XAML. 
Я почему-то не могу вкурить как это сделать... Точнее как обратится к конкретной ячейке.

Comment: @PashaPash: Первоначально вопрос был онтопичным, посмотрите в историю.

Comment: @VladD могу откатить и закрыть как дубликат

Comment: @PashaPash: Ага, это скорее дубликат, чем оффтопик.

Comment: Объясните что нужно сделать..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень просто.

```
grid.Children.Add(button);
Grid.SetRow(button, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(button, 3);
```

Comment: Сделал так как вы порекоммендовали, однако не сработало - я добавил пример в задание.

Comment: @РоманТимохов: А как вы создаёте `Grid`? Может, вы забыли добавить в `Grid` `RowDefinitions` и `ColumnDefinitions`?

Comment: Нет, не забыл..

Comment: Сори, я разобрался. Я забыл вызвать эту функцию))

Comment: @РоманТимохов: Вот и отлично!